# How to get value from HTML tag stored in a variable?

Tags: html, xml, google-apps-script

I want to fetch calenders details of all users in a domain. I am trying to do this by using UrlFetchApp and send get request to server.

```
var urlFetch = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchArgs);
```

I passed all required parameters for this. But its gives **302 Moved Temporarily** server error. Sometimes its work but not always.
To remove this problem, i have to send again a get request to server with same content and parameters. When send first get request its return a url, a session id is appended to it.
so i need to send a request with this new url.

I used the following code for this:

```
function getCalender(){
    var users = UserManager.getAllUsers(); 
     var scope = 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/';
     var fetchArgs = googleOAuth_('calender', scope);

     for(i=0;i<users.length;i++ ){
          var url ='https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/'+users[i].getEmail()+'/private/full';

          try{
          var urlFetch=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,fetchArgs)

         }
          catch(err){
            Logger.log(err)

          }
      }
}

function googleOAuth_(name,scope) {
  var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
  oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey("");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret("");
  return {oAuthServiceName:name, 
  oAuthUseToken:"always",
  content:'application/atom+xml', 
  method:"GET",
  Authorization:'GoogleLogin auth=?'};
}
```

When i print err value its gives:

```
Exception: Request failed for  returned code 302. Server response: <HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Moved Temporarily</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Moved Temporarily</H1>
The document has moved <A HREF="https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/<email-id>/private/full?gsessionid=y1oQCjGH3LqTKJgyh9BlhA">here</A>.
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I want to get this moved id to send a new request with new url.
Please give me any idea to solve this problem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be done by converting server response in a string, then split the string to get special text from the paragraph.